# Smart and auto indent not indenting as expected for JSX

Tags: indentation, filetype-javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to get vim to correctly indent the next line in a JSX block.

Currently when I press enter, the cursor goes slightly behind where it should be. In the example below, my cursor starts after `<Switch>`. Then, when I press enter, the cursor is on the next line, but 4 spaces before where it should be.

```
// This is in a class, in a file foo.js.
render() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>|start
    |got
        |want
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

These are the settings in my vimrc file.

```
" Global settings.
set autoindent
set shiftwidth=4
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
filetype plugin indent on
syntax off

" Javascript specific settings.
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

If I'm not in a JSX block, then the indentation seems to work fine.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);|start
  |got
}
```

P.D.
I'd like to avoid installing a plugin, if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow your desired v. happening behavior, but try not enabling `smartindent`—it's only good for C-style (brace) languages. You don't want it on globally (and `ftplugin indent on` should enable it automatically when you need it).

Comment: `filetype plugin indent on` disables `smartindent` in this case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the treesitter plugin for this behaviour. Add the following to your configuration.

```
 require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
   indent = {
     enable = true,
   },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foo.js` is assigned the `javascript` filetype while its content is *not* actually JavaScript. Ideally, your JSX file should have the `.jsx` extension, which would make Vim assign the *theoretically correct* `javascriptreact` filetype.

Now, I wrote "theoretically correct" because Vim indeed has specific filetypes for `.jsx` and `.tsx`, `javscriptreact` and `typescriptreact`, but those are only stubs that source their `javascript` and `typescript` buddies. This has been the case for quite some time and it will stay that way as long as no one steps forward.

Ironically, the `getJavascriptIndent()` function defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/javascript.vim` has *some* logic for JSX, but that logic is only triggered if the current highlight group stack matches the pattern `xml\|jsx`. Since none of the highlight groups defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim` contains the string `jsx` or `xml`, the function never takes the `jsx` path.

From there, you have two paths:

- report the problem in Vim's issue tracker,
- look around for an alternative indent script for JSX.